# Extract chain components from mixed graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a mixed acyclic graph consists of directed and undirected edges, I want to decompose this graph into a directed graph of chain components (each node within a chain component will be connected to each other only with undirected edges) and their orderings.

I am confused whether I should first topologically sort all directed edges, and then hunt undirected edges as chain components, or first should I go over all undirected edges and give them group id's and then find some directed edges to connect those components.

Since the graph is acyclic, I think it's possible to order them from low-numbered components to high-numbered ones, but couldn't come up with a solid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both of your methods would work fine.

To my mind the second method seems more natural.

If I was doing this in networkx I would implement your second method by:

1. Create a new graph H containing all vertices but only the undirected edges.
2. Call [connected_components](http://networkx.github.com/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components) on H to extract the chain components and assign each component a different group id.
3. Create a new graph F with 1 node for each group id.  Connect groups in F with directed edges based on the directed edges in the original graph.
4. Call [topological_sort](http://networkx.github.com/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort.html#networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort) on F to compute the ordering of the group ids.

Comment: I recently tried what you suggested here, it largely works. However it misses chain components with a single node. Would you mind editing your answer accordingly ?

Comment: Thanks, I've modified step 1 to mention that all vertices should be included.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalence relation that defines a chain component is the following by [Drton 2009](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bj/1251463279):
Define two vertices `v_0` and `v_k` in a chain graph G to be equivalent if there exists a path `(v_0,..., v_k)` such that `v_i − v_{i+1}` in G for all 0 ≤ i ≤ k − 1.

The equivalence classes under this equivalence relation are the chain components of G. Rougly speaking this means all connected components of the graph made from undirected edges of the chain graph, plus all the nodes that are incident with only directed edges, plus all the nodes that have no neighbors at all, which amounts to [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14518552/7330813)

Here is the function that correctly decomposes the chain graph CH-Asia given in Cowell 2005,Probabilistic Networks and ...,  p. 110 Fig. 6.1.
It is part of a [graphical models library](https://github.com/Viva-Lambda/graphical-models) I have been developing as hobby project.

Though it uses custom data structures, it should not be too hard to adapt to other code bases involving graphical models.

```py
def get_chain_components(self) -> Set[Set[Node]]:
    """!
    """
    # filter out undirected edges
    edges = set()
    for e in self.edges():
        if e.type() == EdgeType.UNDIRECTED:
            edges.add(e)

    # make a graph from undirected edges
    undi = UndiGraph.from_graph(Graph.from_edge_node_set(edges, self.nodes()))
    return undi.get_components_as_node_set()
```

Answer (score 0):

A mixed graph such you describe is again a directed graph. Simply replace each undirected edge with two directed ones pointing in opposite directions.

Also you can't have an acyclic graph that has undirected edges. At least a cycle of length 2 will always exist, so I am not sure what do you mean by this.

It seems you are looking for the strongly connected components in this graph so I advice you to use [Tarjan's algorith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) for finding them.